# TensorFlow: Error while parsing .d file

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, bazel

I use Ubuntu 15.10. Currently I am building TensorFlow from source, following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).

My installation is successful, save for the last step: "Build your target with GPU support".

When I run this command from the root of my source tree:

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer`

I see the following output:

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /home/me/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:549:1: error while parsing .d file: /home/me/.cache/bazel/_bazel_me/38a03c514c8dc954778fc9a555bce3de/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/_objs/colorspace_op_gpu/tensorflow/core/kernels/colorspace_op_gpu.cu.d (No such file or directory).
nvcc warning : option '--relaxed-constexpr' has been deprecated and replaced by option '--expt-relaxed-constexpr'.
In file included from third_party/gpus/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:76:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
third_party/gpus/cuda/include/host_config.h:115:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!
  ^
Target //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

There are several things I do not understand:

1. Why is the `.d` file missing?
2. What does this mean?

> nvcc warning : option '--relaxed-constexpr' has been deprecated and replaced by option '--expt-relaxed-constexpr'.

3. My GCC version is 5.2.1. Does this mean there is no way I can build TensorFlow from source?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check my answer. Also, there is a better place to post such ubuntu-related questions - [here](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider installing and temporary selecting an older version of the `gcc`:

```
apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

Then update your alternatives:

```
update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
```

After compiling TensorFlow you can use previous version of `gcc` calling above command with proper path to `/usr/bin/gcc-5.x`.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/26518/519613) you can find more detailed answer.